# when is the right time to start applying for a postdoc/RA position

Tags: postdocs, electrical-engineering

I am writing my thesis; I have another 12 months fellowship and time frame to finish my 4 years PhD in Electrical Engineering from one of the country's (In north-western Europe) top universities.

I have published one (as a first author) in the IEEE journal (Impact Factor 9 around). I have submitted another two papers in the so-called A-graded top journal in control theory-related areas; hopefully, they will be accepted and get published in another six months or so.

I am sure, that during my PhD time frame, I will not be able to publish anymore, even if I have 2 other works(papers) almost completed say 70%, and hopefully they will be in the arXive, when I will be graduating next year.

My question is when shall I start applying for a post-doc? Now or when do the other two get accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that half a year is not sufficient time to get your next position and suggest that you start immediately. There will be a lot of competition for any job in the current market and others are already getting into the market.

You don't know that the new work will be accepted, but the fact that you are active and have papers under consideration is a plus. You are in a position to share them with a potential employer who wants to know more in detail what you are doing.

You won't be hired based on a bunch of numbers (such as published papers). Give yourself sufficient lead time, and even a bit of time to absorb a rejection or two and still come out fine. Go. Do it.

Comment: Thanks a million Buffy, for your green signal :)

Comment: hmmm, "Thanks a million"? Should I send my bank code?

Comment: Sure Once I get a postdoc :D :D

Comment: Send it here, actually: https://en.unesco.org, And good luck. Or as we say, "woof".

Comment: :D :D OKay sure :)